# "What's the probability that if $X, Y$?" vs. "If $X$, what's the probability that $Y$?"

Tags: probability

From: Philip Johnson-Laird [BA PhD Psychology (UCL)](https://dof.princeton.edu/about/clerk-faculty/emeritus/philip-nicholas-johnson-laird), Stuart Professor of Psychology Emeritus at Princeton.    (Author isn't  a logician.)    [*How We Reason*  (1st edn 2008)](https://www.amazon.ca/How-We-Reason-Philip-Johnson-Laird/dp/0199551332). p. 309.

> The appeal of this account, I suspect, relies on the migration effect that I
>   described earlier. Someone asks us:
>
> > **[1.]** What’s the probability that if there is a circle then there is a triangle?
>
> Migration leads us to construe the question as equivalent to:
>
> > **[2.]** If there is a circle then what’s the probability that there is triangle?
>
> This construal converts the original question into a direct request for a conditional probability. It is hard to resist this construal because it’s warranted
>   by the grammar of subordinate clauses. Yet, it is misleading, because of the
>   equivalence between conditionals of this sort and disjunctions, and the probability of disjunctions depends, not on a conditional probability, but on the
>   possibilities in which they hold.

I'm not understanding the distinction between 1 and 2; they both represent  $\Pr(triangle|circle)$ to me.

3. Which is $\Pr(∃ \; triangle|∃ \; circle)$?
4. What probability does the other question signify?

Comment: Let $T$ be "Triangle exists" and $C$ be "Circle Exists". (1) Asks for the probability of an implication. In set theory $C$ implies $T$ is $T \subset C$ so the it seems to be asking for $P(T \subset C) = P(C^c \cup T).$ I'm not sure what sample space would support events $T$ and $C.$  (2) To me, anyhow, pretty clearly, $P(T|C).$ // This seems to be some sort of an exercise in philosophy rather than logic or probability. Philosopher Schopenhauer: "Philosophy is the systematic abuse of a terminology established just for that purpose."

Answer (score 2):

Bit hard to tell - which of course is exactly why in mathematics we try as far as possible to have precise terminology and notation.  However here is my interpretation.

I'm assuming the problem envisages a number of diagrams which have circles, triangles, both or neither.  Let $T$ and $C$ be the events "there is a triangle" and "there is a circle".  Then in my view, probability [2] is the conditional probability $P(T|C)$.

For [1], "if $C$ then $T$" is logically equivalent to "(not $C$) or $T$" and so the probability is $P(\overline C\cup T)$.

**Example**.  Suppose there are $10$ diagrams with the following joint distribution:
$$\matrix{&C&\overline C\cr T&1&2\cr \overline T&3&4\cr}$$
Then
$$\hbox{probability [1]}=P(\overline C\cup T)=\frac7{10}$$
while
$$\hbox{probability [2]}=P(T|C)=\frac14\ .$$

Comment: Not sure it's right, but not sure _anything_ is right. (+1)

Comment: @BruceET Agreed :)